# Rewrite sometext/ to sometext/sometext.php, forbid direct acces to sometext.php

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'am struggling with this for a couple of days.

Folder structure is:

index/files/pages/

In main folder (index) there is **index.php** - this is the only index.php file in whole page. 
In files folder there are php files that are actually pages of the website.
In files folder there are couple of more folders (pages) that hold different pages - I just grouped the php fiels into folders to keep it tidy.

I am trying to achivie this.

1. When I enter url like **index/files/pages/somename.php** - I want to get 404 or whatever
2. When I enter url like **index/files/somename** - this gets rewritten to **index/files/pages/somename.php**, but the address looks clean.

Now whatever I do I can't get both rules to work, either one overwrites another or nothing works, I get 500 all the time.

Here is my rule that actually works:

`RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-z]+)$ pages/$1.php` - this is the scenario 2 and its ok.

Now when I add rule that handles direct access to php files, the previous rule is also affected and gets overwritten and everything throws 404, 500 etc. Flags like [L] etc don't have any effect, changing the order also does nothing.

Also I want to forbid direct access to **index.php** and redirect to index folder (and show clean url)

Here are some additional rules i tried, but no result. As I said earlier setting flags give no results.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/pages\/.*\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-z]+)$ pages/$1.php 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(.*)\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [R=404,L]
```

Thankx and regards

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ index/ [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ [F]

RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Not working - index.php is redirected to index folder - taht is ok.
I can still acces php of the page(index/fiels/pages/somename.php, but get 404 when accesing page via clean url, that is: index/files/somename - not working

Comment: I got it.

Here is the final ruleset:

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*/.*/(.*).php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*/(.*).php$ [L,R=404,NC,NE]
    
    RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-z]*)$ pages/$1.php [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/index.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mypage/ [R=301,L]

thanx for answers, it lead me somehow to this.

Comment: That's great to know. You can mark the answer as accepted if you believe you got any help from it.